# how can use private void in the onclick?

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

how can use private void in the onclick?

when the user clicks the item, I hope I can calculate the like count, so how can I do?

this is my code

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                holder.likeCount.setText("1" + " likes");
                holder.likeImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
                private void loadLikes() {
                    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Load...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

but it has an error code;

error: illegal start of expression private void loadLikes() {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you're trying to declare a function inside another function but java doesn't support nested functions (only through Lambda and anonymous classes). You can declare `loadLikes()` function outside the listener callback as follows:

```
 private void loadLikes() {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Load...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
```

And then call it inside `onClick()`

```
holder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            holder.likeCount.setText("1" + " likes");
            holder.likeImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
            loadLikes();
        }
    });
```

cheers :)

Comment: but, if I use this method, how can use holder?
error: package holder does not exist
            holder.likeCount.setText("1" + " likes");

Comment: Fixed the typo.